# Script fails to run when run in headless chrome, but works fine when headed

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm setting up my init method like this.

```
def __init__(self, ip_address):
    """ Initialize a new Printer_Webpage object."""
    self.ip_address = ip_address

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    # Ignore lack of cert for each printer web page.
    # Otherwise, can't open page.
    self.browser.accept_untrusted_certs = True
```

And accessing the printer like this.

```
def login(self):
    """Navigates through the login page for the printer."""
    # Open login page
    self.browser.get(f'https://{self.ip_address}/wcd/top.xml')

    # STEPS TO LOGIN:
    # 1) Select 'Administrator' radio button and click.
    self.browser.find_element_by_id('Admin').click()
    # 2) Select Login button and click.
    self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' \
                                        and @value='Login']").click()
    # 3) Select admin (user mode)
    self.browser.find_element_by_id('R_ADM2').click()
    # 4) Select password field and input PASSWORD, then submit.
    password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_id('Admin_Pass')
    password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The whole script runs fine in headed chrome, but when run headless I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Admin"}
```

Initially I thought that perhaps the elements hadn't loaded yet (takes a few seconds when run headed), but even a wait of 30 seconds doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What certificate are you using on your https server? You might be interested in this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739

Comment: How are you implementing `wait of 30 seconds`?

Comment: @DebanjanB I was using time.sleep(30).

Comment: @DebanjanB I've also tried `self.browser.implicitly_wait(30)`, and that hasn't worked either.